# Crime statistics of New York City neighbourhoods

Tags: security, new-york-city

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/8360/39662) refers to NYC.gov as a source for crime statistics for each NYC neighbourhood. Apparently, the links is broken and I cannot find anything on the official site regarding this.

Is there any resource on the web where I can check the recent crime stats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New York crime statistics are available [at the the NYPD website under Crime Prevention](http://www.nyc.gov/html/nypd/html/crime_prevention/crime_statistics.shtml). You'll find city wide statistics and statistics for each precinct— a [map of precincts](http://www.nyc.gov/html/nypd/html/precinct_maps/precinct_finder.shtml) is also available.

e.g.

[image: Sample crime statistics from the New York Police Department]

An alternative point of view would be a visualation of crime, which are typically found by searching for "mash ups", e.g.

[NYC Crime Map](http://nyc.pediacities.com/fsmaps/NYCCrimeMap/)

[image]

The site [Flowing Data](https://flowingdata.com/2009/06/23/20-visualizations-to-understand-crime/) has some pointers to other crime visualisation sites.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @choster. I guess I have the bad habit of using "here" for links.

Comment: No worries; I don't expect everyone to be an accessibility consultant. :)

Comment: Thanks @Berwyn! The stats give you data about crime and the relative changes to previous time frames per each precinct. Is there also some information about the population framed by one precinct? Do they have the same size? It is hard to make sense of the provided data otherwise (except of filtering which neighbourhood is becoming worse and which is freed by hipsters of course :-)

Comment: @Marcus What you're probably looking for is a mash-up. Have updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

After researching it again, I found now a map you can play around with on NYC.gov https://maps.nyc.gov/crime/ containing up-to-date information from crime statistics.

You can change the 'map type' (e.g. check for precinct stats or the crime location with a scatter plot), change the 'Date range' and sort for specific crimes.

As an anactdotaral reference, I can say that this map get updates very soon. For example, a burglary was added within two weeks (validated via the exact location it actually happened).